# Nginx - SSL, HSTS & proxying requests to a different CN

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, azure

We are using Nginx as a reverse proxy, and would like to allow site visitors to download a file from an Azure Blob

```
            server {
            listen 443;
            ssl_certificate /sslcert/ssl.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /sslcert/com.key;
            server_name get.domain.com;

            location / {

            proxy_redirect  off;
            proxy_pass   http://oururl.blob.core.windows.net/;
            }
```

However, HSTS does not allow this request as the backend is presenting a certificate (?) with a different Common Name. Even with HSTS disabled we would still see a warning about host authenticity.

What is curious is that we are using proxy_pass for local backends without any issues.

Works:

```
/home/user# curl get.domain.com
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code><Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
```

Doesn't work:

```
/home/user# curl https://get.domain.com
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'get.domain.com'
```

And finally - yes, we are aware of the subdomain masking feature of Azure Storage. We are not using it because we are blanket forwarding our subdomains to the Nginx IP for custom handling.

UPDATE:

```
curl -k -v get.domain.com
    * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    *   Trying 140.17.8.10...
    * Connected to get.domain.com (140.17.8.10) port 443 (#0)
    * successfully set certificate verify locations:
    *   CAfile: none
      CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
    * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
    * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
    * SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    * Server certificate:
    *        subject: CN=*.blob.core.windows.net
    *        start date: 2015-06-10 01:45:43 GMT
    *        expire date: 2017-06-09 01:45:43 GMT
    *        issuer: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; OU=Microsoft IT; CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
    *        SSL certificate verify ok.
    > GET /releases/RELEASES HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
    > Host: get.domain.com
    > Accept: */*
    >
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Content-Length: 79
    < Content-Type: application/octet-stream
    < Content-MD5: IK8vn1QxUXipiqosdijfdA==
    < Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 07:03:15 GMT
    < ETag: 0x8D3159E48B72E88
    * Server Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 is not blacklisted
    < Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
    < x-ms-request-id: XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
    < x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
    < x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
    < x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
    < Date: Sat, 09 Jan 2016 06:46:43 GMT
    <
    * Connection #0 to host get.domain.com left intact
```

Comment: At the moment your `proxypass` line goes to a plain `http://` backend , is that a typo in the question or reflects that your actual config? Because https authentication with a client certificate is never going to fly then.

Comment: What does `curl -k -v https://get.domain.com/` show?  In particular, I'm hoping it will list the SANs that `curl` sees, along with the response headers, _etc_.

Comment: Updated the config - I did use https with a client cert, and have also tried http without one. Removed the client cert lines for simplicity.

Comment: Still, the curl output would be useful.

Comment: Curl added above.